# Doctrine + Symfony2: Forms: Removing deleted element from a collection that is contained in another collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So i have a form that contains a collection which contains another collection, both collections have `allow_add` & `allow_delete` set to `true`. but i'm facing a problem when deleting some items from the child collection. i'm following Symfony2 documentation and For simplicity i will use the same documentation example from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

```
class Task
{
    protected $description;

    protected $tags;

    ....
}


class Tag
{
    protected $name;

    protected $categories;

     ....
}



class Category
{
    protected $name;

    ....
}
```

now after the user update the form, i have to ensuring the database persistence by comparing the original Collection with the new one. From Symfony2 Documentation:

```
$originalTags = new ArrayCollection();
// Create an ArrayCollection of the current Tag objects in the database
foreach ($task->getTags() as $tag) {
    $originalTags->add($tag);
}
```

here `Tags` get copied by value while `Categories` in `tags` still get copied by reference and once the user delete one from the form it got removed from `$originalTags` as well.

**I solved the issue but it got pretty complicated and i'm sure that this approach is not the best so i'm looking for a better approach**

---

**Additional info**

i tried to implement `__clone` on class `Tag` like this:

in `Tag`:

```
public function __clone()
{
    $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

and i changed how `$originalTags` created to:

```
$originalTags = new ArrayCollection();
foreach ($task->getTags() as $tag) {
    $cat_array = array();
    $t = clone $tag;

    foreach($tag->getCategories() as $category) {
      $t->addCategory(clone $category);
    }
    $originalTags->add($t);
}
```

and this is how i calculated the changeset and saved the entity:

```
foreach ($originalTags as $tag) {
     if (false === $task->getTags()->exists(function ($key, $element) use ($tag) {if($element->getId() == $tag->getId() )return true;  })) {
         $temp = $entityManager->find('...\Tag', $tag->getId());
         $entityManager->remove($temp);
         } else {
            foreach($task->getTags() as $t)
            {
               if($t->getId() == $tag->getId())
               {
                   $originalTag = $t;
               }
            }
            foreach ($tag->getCategories() as $category) {
               if (false === $originalTag->getCategories()->exists(function ($key, $element) use ($category) {if($element->getId() == $category->getId() )return true;})) {
                   $temp = $entityManager->find('...\Category', $category->getId());
                   $entityManager->remove($temp);
               }
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with something like

```
$originalTags = new ArrayCollection();
// Create an ArrayCollection of the current Tag objects in the database
foreach ($task->getTags() as $tag) {
    $cat_array = array();
    foreach($tag->getCategories() as $categories) {
       $cat_array[] = clone $categories;
    }
    $originalTags->addCategories($cat_array); //you have to write this method
}
```

We have to verify something, however, since if you `clone` a "doctrine" object, `entity manager` could "lost" its reference and won't be able to persist it again to db (if you need, of course)

Comment: was trying with something similar to this it seems once the object is cloned comparing the original and the new `$category` fails, `$tag->getCategories()->contains($category)` will always return false.

Comment: Of course it will fail; they aren't the same object... I mean, you could override that `->contains()` operation to compare only, for example, entity id (or primary key, if you like) and do the tricks

Comment: true, but lets say i cloned a `category` then doctrine can't manage it anymore, after that, the user deletes that category so it's not exists anymore in `$tag->getCategories()` so once i compare between the original category and the new one, i will find that missing category so i need to delete it, but i can't delete it from the original array cuz it's cloned nor from the object it self because it has been deleted in by the Form class

Comment: @ra_htial: yeah, I understand what you mean but I can't - at the moment - help you more than this :(